# Chrome and MS Edge does not share the same session cookie for the same domain, for separate browser instance

Tags: session, cookies, browser, instance

I am testing my Asp.Net Core 3.1 web app for session cookie behaviors.

I created a very simple app with login functionality which works perfectly. After I log in, I can access a protected page (with [Authorize] attribute).

Then I tested the following scenarios.

After log in,

1. Chrome/Edge: Open a new tab to access the protected page - it works (no login screen appears)
2. Chrome/Edge: Open a new window (same instance) to access the protected page - it works (no login screen appears)
3. Chrome/Edge: Open a new instance to access the protected page - ***then it shows login screen, not authenticated***

However, when I run using IE, all the above cases, the accepted as authenticated (no login screen appears)

What should I do to share the same session cookie for separate browser instances for Chrome and Edge?